# When using 'Send an email from a shared mailbox (V2)', can you send from a Microsoft Teams group email address?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, microsoft-teams

I am getting this error:

```
{
  "status": 403,
  "message": "Group Shard is used in non-Groups URI.\r\nclientRequestId: *****\r\nserviceRequestId: *****",
  "error": {
    "message": "Group Shard is used in non-Groups URI.",
    "code": "ErrorGroupIsUsedInNonGroupURI",
    "originalMessage": "Group Shard is used in non-Groups URI."
  },
  "source": "office365-ae.azconn-ae.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

when trying to `Send an email from a shared mailbox (V2)`:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#send-an-email-from-a-shared-mailbox-(v2)

I am using the group email address that is created by default when creating a Microsoft Team (it is selectable when typing it in the `Mailbox Address` field).

I am a Team Owner.

Should this work?

If so, how can this error be resolved?

Otherwise, what options do I have other than `Send an email (V2)` so that emails are not sent from my personal email address?

I tried `Send an email (V3)` in the past, but it wasn't working in corporate environment for some reason (I cannot remember why), so have been hesitant to try it again since.

Answer (score 0):

This would not work. We can not use the Microsoft Teams group in the Mailbox Address field.

Here is a similar issue for your reference: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Using-a-Shared-Mailbox-from-a-Team-Group-Shard-error/td-p/722588

Office 365 Group address cannot be used as Shared Mailbox address:  https://docs.microsoft.com/cs-cz/connectors/office365/#known-issues-and-limitations

Currently, `Send an email (V2)` is your only option.

Comment: Is there any update on this, i.e a way to send email from a Microsoft Teams email address?  There is [a comment here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Send-email-from-O365-group-mailbox/idi-p/102458) which mentions a [Office 365 Groups Mail](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365groupsmail) connector - but i am not sure if that can be used to SEND an email (they use the terms 'conversations' and 'threads' and when i tried the action 'Start a new group conversation by creating a thread' - the flow completes but I don't know where the 'message' goes).

Comment: update:  i think i figured out what the above does (even though it doesn't solve my original issue, i will add description here as reference ) - i can see the 'messages' sent by the groups mail flow are in the 'Sent' folder of my tenant account email, and they are addressed To the group email address of the Team (and i cannot see those emails because the Team was created in Teams and therefore the associated group email address is [hidden by default](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/office-365-groups#how-microsoft-365-groups-work-with-teams)).